TemplateRef gets undefined for the nested component, when passing as content child
I have a component and im passing a template "exampleTemplate" to this component
<standard-form> <ng-template #exampleTemplate></ng-template </standard-form>
Inside the standard-form, there is another component which also expects a content child
Passing this exampleTemplate template to the tab-group component
<tab-group> <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="exampleTemplate" </tab-group>
this is not working
I tried to test it in the both the components
Able to receive and able to print the template in the standard-form component, but in the nested component tab-group - template is undefined always
Tried to print it using the ngAfterContentInit

What you need is to use another ng-template wrapping your ng-container. You are projecting your content only once.
<tab-group> 
  <ng-template> 
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="exampleTemplate"><ng-container>
  </ng-template>
 </tab-group>

Also, verify that you are using @ContentChild(TemplateRef).
Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kv4jtq

yes, using contentchild only but this is not working
